# Place even distributed points on net with holes

Tags: algorithm, math, linear-algebra, distance, differential-equations

given N yellow dots that needs to be placed on the black-blue map.
Red arrows show the distance along the street to the next yellow dot(s) you can visit.
yellow dots can not be placed on the blue street, but the distance counts nevertheless.

My problem is to minimize the sqrt(sum(distance_xy ^2) ) , so the yellow dots has the maximum equal distribution.
The number space is N (natural numbers) , so points cant be placed on 10.23, only on  10 or 11.

[image]
this image shows a solution, thats obviously not the perfect and not the worst solution.

**My approch(es)**

Until now i dont find any O(N) solution, but if i imagine magnets that repeal each other, they would distribute themself. But it may depend on the starting conditions, but the starting conditions may be O(N).

I could cut the map into a tree, i could simulate magnetism but im not sure if any of this would end in perfect solution.
until now i only got a genetic algorithm to deliver a good result, but maybe someone know a "this is the XY problem, that is the solution" one.

any help is appreciated :-)

Comment: Why wouldn't you place all the yellow dots on the right rectangle?  What are the sizes of the rectangles in points?

Comment: if i would place all to the right, there would be a long distance all around the left rectangle. In other words, this would not be even distributed. The size of the points are zero , the outer rectangle would be for example 25x20 units. its a modification of the k-center problem, imagine you have a straight line, 100m and 2 yellow dots. if you want the minimum of the maximum distance that you can be away from a yellow dot, thats 25 because you place the dots at 25 and 75 and you can be  at 0,50 and 100. that idea now projected to the map above.